# OSGi and database drivers

Tags: spring, osgi, hsqldb, drivers

I've been trying to deploy a bundle to servicemix which creates a hsqldb datasource.

So far I've had no success with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:mem:temp
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
```

I've deployed a bundle to osgi that contains the HSQLDB driver like so:

```
karaf@root> packages:exports | grep hsql
205 org.hsqldb; version="1.8.0.10"          
205 org.hsqldb.index; version="1.8.0.10"    
205 org.hsqldb.jdbc; version="1.8.0.10"     
205 org.hsqldb.lib; version="1.8.0.10"      
205 org.hsqldb.lib.java; version="1.8.0.10" 
205 org.hsqldb.persist; version="1.8.0.10"  
205 org.hsqldb.resources; version="1.8.0.10"
205 org.hsqldb.rowio; version="1.8.0.10"    
205 org.hsqldb.sample; version="1.8.0.10"   
205 org.hsqldb.scriptio; version="1.8.0.10" 
205 org.hsqldb.store; version="1.8.0.10"    
205 org.hsqldb.types; version="1.8.0.10"    
205 org.hsqldb.util; version="1.8.0.10"     
205 org.hsqldb.util.sqltool; version="1.8.0.10"
```

Then within my bundle in the Spring configuration I've got the following:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:temp"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

And the manifest for the bundle:

```
Import-Package: org.hsqldb
```

Have I missed something? Any ideas will be great as I'm struggling to find anything online.

Comment: Issue resolved! Update to Java6 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having realised no formal answer has been given for this question, as I wrote in the above comment, the solution was simple. It was purely the case of upgrading to Java 6.